# Javascript Expression that take only alphabates

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have done something like this
but its not working
can anyone please correct following `regex`.

`/^[a-zA-Z.\s]+$/`

Comment: What is the output you want? Give some examples

Comment: I have a input textbox it should take only take alphabetic values(say first name, last name etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only *alphabets*, remove `.` from regex. This will match all the alphabets and spaces.

```
/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/
```

I'll also recommend you to use  instead of `\s`

```
/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/
```

so that, other space characters(tabs, etc.) will not matched.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
/^[a-zA-Z]*$/
```

Change the * to **+** if you don't want to allow empty matches.

**References:**

[**Character classes ([...]), Anchors (^ and $), Repetition (+, *)**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

The `/` are just delimiters, it denotes the start and the end of the regex. One use of this is now you can use [modifiers](http://modifiers) on it.